# Изменение стейта сестренского компонента через родительский | react

Tags: reactjs

есть компонентная структура.

Компонент 1 в котором происходит генерация пропов для компонента 2 и 3

Как при нажатии на кнопки внутри 2 элемента, изменять состояние 3го элемента?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [подъем состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: а без классовых компонент это не получиться сделать?

Comment: Получится, можно использовать функциональные компоненты. Речь идет о том, что вы состояние поднимаете до общего родительского компонента. Само состояние передаете в компонент 3, а метод его изменения передаете в компонент 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Component1` создаем состояние и передаем его в `Component3`. А в `Component2` передаем функцию, которая может изменять это состояние.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Component1 = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <Component2 updateData={setState} />
      <Component3 data={state} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Component2 = ({ updateData }) => {
  return <button onClick={() => updateData('clicked')}>Click me</button>;
};

const Component3 = ({ data }) => {
  return <div>{data}</div>
};
```